# GROUP BY vs. ARBITRARY vs. JOIN for extra grouping columns

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a column `user_id` that I want to GROUP BY in a query that contains several calculations/CTEs. Now let's say I have two other columns `user_name` and `city` that I also want to include in the end result of the query that are guaranteed to have a 1:1 relationship with `user_id`.

What is the best way to carry these columns through? Assume best means both performance and code clarity? Example simplified code is shown, but assume there may be multiple stages of group bys on those columns in the CTEs so you'd be carrying/grouping all the way through the query for options 1 and 2.

1. Group by all three columns at every group by.

```
WITH cte1 AS (
  SELECT user_id, user_name, city, other_grouping_column, my_metrics FROM my_table
), 
cte2 AS (
  SELECT
    user_id,
    user_name,
    city,
    other_grouping_column,
    some_agg_metric1
  FROM cte1
  GROUP BY 
    user_id,
    user_name,
    city,
    other_grouping_column
)
SELECT 
  user_id,
  user_name,
  city,
  some_agg_metric2
FROM cte2
GROUP BY 
  user_id,
  user_name,
  city
```

2. Use ARBITRARY() instead of GROUP BY on `user_name` and `city` at every group by.

```
WITH cte1 AS (
  SELECT user_id, user_name, city, other_grouping_column, my_metrics FROM my_table
), 
cte2 AS (
  SELECT
    user_id,
    ARBITRARY(user_name) AS user_name,
    ARBITRARY(city) AS city,
    other_grouping_column,
    some_agg_metric1
  FROM cte1
  GROUP BY 
    user_id,
    other_grouping_column
)
SELECT 
  user_id,
  ARBITRARY(user_name) AS user_name,
  ARBITRARY(city) AS city,
  some_agg_metric2
FROM cte2
GROUP BY 
  user_id
```

3. Use JOIN at the end to original table (or possibly to initial CTE)

```
WITH cte1 AS (
  SELECT user_id, other_grouping_column, my_metrics FROM my_table
), 
cte2 AS (
  SELECT
    user_id,
    other_grouping_column,
    some_agg_metric1
  FROM cte1
  GROUP BY 
    user_id,
    other_grouping_column
), 
cte3 AS (
  SELECT 
    user_id,
    some_agg_metric2
  FROM cte2
  GROUP BY 
    user_id
)
SELECT 
  cte3.user_id,
  my_table.user_name,
  my_table.city,
  cte3.some_agg_metric
FROM cte3
JOIN my_table
  ON cte3.user_id = my_table.user_id
```

Comment: ARBITRARY? Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Improving the performance of a query may largely depend on the DBMS you're actually using. Because every DBMS has their own behaviour and better/worse set of tools to address specific tasks. Keeping your sample generic may easily have the side effect of getting generic non-optimized answers for it.

Comment: Most DBMS (MySQL is one exception) require that all columns are either included in the GROUP BY or are aggregated - so you don’t have an option on how you define your SQL statements. In addition, CTEs help you write SQL statements by breaking up a complex query into smaller parts - they don’t, necessarily, influence how the query optimiser decides to execute the overall query.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to answer. You want to write an aggregation query where you end up with one result row per user_id. You have this query:

```
SELECT user_id, user_name, city, other_grouping_column, my_metrics
FROM my_table
```

which you start as a base for your aggregations. This means that in a normalized database this is not the users table, because then there would be no aggregation necessary to get one row per user. But if it is not the users table, then there must be no guarantee that you find the same user name and city in all rows per user_id in the table, because that would mean that your database is not normalized.

Your question is: "what is the best way to write the query", but it seems it should better be "what is the best way to design this database". There must be two tables, the users table and a table with the metrics. The users table will contain the user's name and address. So, what you'll do in order to query these tables with an aggregation per user is: aggregate the metrics table with `GROUP BY user_id`, and then join the users table to add name and city to the result.